# How can I parse a json response.body to store a key's value in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am receiving a json response (response.body) from the api call I am making with my model and in my controller I would like to parse it to store its id key's value in my session[:user_id].

I've tried to implement it in the following way

```
parsed_body = JSON.parse(User.new.get_credentials, :symbolize_names => true)
puts "The parsed_body is: #{parsed_body}"
session[:user_id] = parsed_body[0][:id]
puts "The session id is: #{session[:user_id]} "
```

The response.body is:

```
{"result":[{"id":"3","username":"Sam","password":"111"},{"id":"4","username":"Harshal","password":"1234"},{"id":"5","username":"Dev","password":"112"},{"id":"6","username":"Lam","password":"113"},{"id":"7","username":"Tim","password":"114"},{"id":"8","username":"Harry","password":"222"}]}
```

The parsed_body is:

```
{:result=>[{:id=>"3", :username=>"Sam", :password=>"111"}, {:id=>"4", :username=>"Harshal", :password=>"1234"}, {:id=>"5", :username=>"Dev", :password=>"112"}, {:id=>"6", :username=>"Lam", :password=>"113"}, {:id=>"7", :username=>"Tim", :password=>"114"}, {:id=>"8", :username=>"Harry", :password=>"222"}]}
```

Here is my code for users controller, user model and sessions controller:

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def create
        @users = User.new(token: user_params).credentials
        parsed_body = JSON.parse(User.new.get_credentials, :symbolize_names => true)
        puts "The parsed_body is: #{parsed_body}"
        session[:user_id] = parsed_body[0][:id]
        puts "The session id is: #{session[:user_id]} "
        redirect_to '/dashboard'
      end

      private 
        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:id, :username, :password).to_hash
        end
end
```

User Model

```
class User

   def initialize(attributes={})
        @token ||= attributes[:token]
    end

   def credentials
        my_connection = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', 8080)
        request = my_connection.post('/restapitrial/index.php/Users/insert/', @token.to_json, "Content-Type" => "application/json")
  end

  def get_credentials
        my_connection = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', 8080)
        request = my_connection.get('/restapitrial/index.php/Users/displayinfo/', "Content-Type" => "application/json")
        puts "The req body is #{request.body}"
        return request.body
  end
end
```

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.find_by(id: login_params[:id])
        if user && user.authenticate(login_params[:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to '/dashboard'
        else
            flash[:login_errors] = ['invalid credentials']
            redirect_to '/'
        end
    end

    private 
        def login_params
            params.require(:login).permit(:id, :username, :password)
        end

end
```

Comment: `parsed_body` has top-level key `:result`, so you probably need `session[:user_id] = parsed_body[:result][0][:id]`, but you haven't given us any hints what is actually wrong in the example you provided. Does it save with wrong id? Or raise exception? By the way, please do not call API from the model.

Comment: @katafrakt it gives a "NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error for the implementation I did (mentioned above). My API is a php file that communicates with the phpmyadmin database so I am interacting with it. Frontend Rails - Backend PHP.

Comment: That would be because `parsed_body[0]` is indeed a `nil`. Try `parsed_body[:result][0][:id]` as I mentioned above.

Comment: @katafrakt As suggested by you I did parsed_body[:result][0][:id]. However, it is just returning me the very 1st id value. What do I do to store the id of the user who registers by inputting his/her id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the last id in the array that is returned then use the

```
parsed_body[:result][-1][:id]
```